# Find a string with in a TEXT type column that contains an XML file and replace a value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Update:
The column that has the XML file has a data type of text.

---

Update 2 (This helped me use xml functions instead of using charindex to manipulate the data):
I created a temp table #tmpXML (id int, xmlField XML). id is the Primary key of my main table and xmlField is the XML value from the text type field. I used XML functions on the XML data field in the temp table and got all the values I needed and I updated my main table with these values.

I found this method to be more efficient and clean than using sql server functions like charindex and substring. This is the reason why I accepted the answer because it helped me use xml functions. Just wanted to clarify.

---

I have a column called `Settings` that contains xml file with user settings.

For example I have 3 users that have the following rows for this column.

XML for the first user id 1:

```
<owner>
    <product userid="1" productid="3" region="North" country="Usa" ></product>
</owner>
```

XML for the first user id 2:

```
<owner>
    <product userid="2" productid="3" selectedView="true" region="North" state="AZ" country="Usa" ></product>
</owner>
```

XML for the first user id 3:

```
<owner>
    <product userid="3" productid="3" selectedView="true" region="South" isSelected="true" state="AZ" country="Usa" ></product>
</owner>
```

As you can see, the attributes can be in any order within the XML files for each user. I have to update all the users to have region = "East". I tried doing it using `CharIndex` and `substring` but it's getting too confusing. Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: That's XML, not a string inside another string. SQL Server supports XML querying and modification

Comment: I have updated the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: But have you tried using the XML functions? Checking the docs? The [replace values of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/replace-value-of-xml-dml?view=sql-server-ver15) article shows how you can modify an XML element identified by an XPath string. The [XML Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) section explains how XML data is stored and used in SQL Server, how to query it, index it, modify it etc

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. Thanks for sharing! I'll check it out.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: `Text` is deprecated data type in MS SQL Server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @joemac12,  How did you accept an answer even if it is for the XML data type, i.e. in a direct contradiction with your question?

Comment: I used a temp table to store the text type as XML, performed all the XML operations on it and updated the main table with the modified values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.modify()` XML function for this, using the `replace value of` syntax

```sql
UPDATE users
SET Settings.modify('replace value of (owner/product/@region)[1] with "East"');
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bfb7840c70369d6166f5affe58429b66)

This only works on one XML document per row.

If you actually have all these nodes in one big blob, you need to run it in a loop

```sql
DECLARE @tries int = 0;
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND @tries < 1000
BEGIN
    UPDATE users
    SET Settings.modify('replace value of (owner/product/@region[. != "East"])[1] with "East"')
    WHERE Settings.exist('owner/product/@region[. != "East"]') = 1;
    SET @tries += 1;
END;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ec83968c9229d913c5b4e00a83d959c4)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a case statement in the select
Case
When colName like '%NORTH%' then replace (colName, NORTH, NEWTEXT
When colName like '%SOUTH%'
etc

You could also create a stored function

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

`Text` is a deprecated data type in the MS SQL Server.
I used `NVARCHAR(MAX)` data type to distinguish it from the natural XML data type for the XML data.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id int primary key, Settings NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tbl VALUES
(1,'<owner>
    <product userid="1" productid="3" region="North" country="Usa" ></product>
</owner>'),
(2,'<owner>
    <product userid="2" productid="3" selectedView="true" region="North" state="AZ" country="Usa" ></product>
</owner>'),
(3,'<owner>
    <product userid="3" productid="3" selectedView="true" region="South" isSelected="true" state="AZ" country="Usa" ></product>
</owner>');

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM @tbl
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST(Settings AS XML)
            .query('<owner><product>
                {
                    for $x in /owner/product/@*
                    return if(local-name($x) ne "region") then $x
                        else attribute region {"East"}
                }
            </product></owner>')) t(x)
)
UPDATE rs
SET rs.Settings  = TRY_CAST(x AS NVARCHAR(MAX));

-- test
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```